# PHP display name of login user

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the name of a user when they are logged in. My code uses `$_SESSIONS` to store the name, but since there no `input` in my login in page, the name doesn't get assign and it ends up being just `hello,` instead of something like `hello, John Smith`.
I've tried using `sql` to select the name by matching the email to the email of the logged in user, and storing that in `$_SESSION` but it still doesn't print name of user.

my `server.php`

```
<?php
include_once "inc/user-connection.php";

session_start();

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);

if (isset($_POST['admin-sign-in'])) {
    if (!empty($email)) {
        if (!empty($password)) {
           
            $sql = 'SELECT email, password FROM admin WHERE email = ?';

            // preparing the SQL statement
            if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result(); // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.

                // If email exists in sign_up table
                if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                    $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    // if password user enters matches the one in the database
                    if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

                        // upon successful login, redirect user to landing apge
                        header("location: dashboard.php");
                        die();
                    } else {
                        // Incorrect password
                        header("location: ../html/sign-in-error.html");
                        die();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Incorrect username
                    header("location: ../html/sign-in-error.html");
                    die();
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }
        } else {
            header("location: ../html/404-error.html");
            die();
        }
    } else {
        header("location: ../html/404-error.html");
        die();
    }
}
```

my `dashboard.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div class="d-block">
                    <h1 class="lead fw-normal text-muted mb-4 px-lg-10">Hello,

                        <?php
                        echo $_SESSION['name'];
                        ?>
                    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. It will damage your data

Comment: ok I will. but if it damages data why is it still included? like why dosent the developer or whoever just remove it from PHP?  @Dharman

Comment: Because if you use it correctly it can be useful to some people. The point is that you are using it incorrectly. Do you understand why you have it in your code? Any function that is used against it purpose can be dangerous to your project. You must understand the code you are writing.

Comment: Well I thought I knew what it did which was to remove special characters before inserting making it less vulnerable, which is why I included in the code. So I should remove it and just have prepared statements?  @Dharman

Comment: This function 100% does not remove any characters. If anything it might add some characters. Also, what do you consider special characters in these circumstances? Yes, you should remove it and just use parameter binding offered by prepared statements.

Comment: Ok I will remove them and use prepared statements.  But you have to understand I am completely new to PHP and learning some of this stuff, so things that seem trivial or obvious to you might not to a newcomer like me. But I know you're trying to help and I appreciate it. @Dharman

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not select the name and you are fetching it.

```
$sql = 'SELECT email, password, name FROM admin WHERE email = ?';
```

or

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ?';
```

should fix the issue.

Additional: you can remove all your else statements since all of it will give the same result.

```
<?php

include_once "inc/user-connection.php";

session_start();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

if (isset($_POST['admin-sign-in'])) {
    if (!empty($email)) {
        if (!empty($password)) {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ?';

            // preparing the SQL statement
            if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result(); // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.

                // If email exists in sign_up table
                if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                    $stmt->bind_result($email, $password, $name);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    // if password user enters matches the one in the database
                    if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

                        // upon successful login, redirect user to landing apge
                        header("location: dashboard.php");
                        die();
                    }
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
    }
    header("location: ../html/404-error.html");
    die();
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked. I should note that you also should include the `$name` in the `$stmt->bind_result` since right now it would be an error since there we are selecting 3 from table but only binding two

Comment: @kevin good catch. I'm just pointing out your problem. I don't even test it. But I will update it.